# Unable to access Information_schema via stored procedure

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I am writing a stored procedure which does involving using information schema in AWS Redshift.

VARIABLES FOR ALL THE Below -

1. Using same user
2. Using same Redshift database (endpoint)

Stored procedure:

```
create or replace procedure dev.gp_information_schema_test
    (tablename varchar(64))
as $$
declare 
table_name varchar(64);
schema_name varchar(64);
counts int;
begin
table_name := split_part(tablename,'.',1);
schema_name:= split_part(tablename,'.',2);
raise info 'table_name - %,Schema_name - %',table_name,schema_name;
counts := (select count(*) from information_schema.tables where table_schema = schema_name);
raise info 'count is -%',counts;
end;
$$
language plpgsql

call dev.gp_information_schema_test('dev.abc');
```

Result :

```
Warnings:
table_name - dev,Schema_name - abc
count is -0

0 rows affected
call executed successfully

Execution time: 0.55s
```

But if I run the same query outside (i.e not via stored procedure), then:

```
select count(*) 
from information_schema.tables 
where table_schema = 'dev'
```

Results:

[image: Result of query not from stored procedure]

I have already read the limitations of stored procedure in the AWS documentation ([Link](https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/redshift/latest/dg/stored-procedure-constraints.html)), but there is no mention of access restriction to system tables.

Comment: Thanks @marc_S for editing the question properly. Will take care from next time .

Answer (score 0):

You can't set the value of a variable from a query using `:=`. Instead you need to use the `SELECT INTO variable` form. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_PLpgSQL-structure.html

Try this SP:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE gp_information_schema_test(tablename VARCHAR(64)) AS
$$
DECLARE
    table_name  VARCHAR(64);
    schema_name VARCHAR(64);
    counts      INT;
BEGIN
    schema_name := split_part(tablename, '.', 1);
    table_name := split_part(tablename, '.', 2);
    RAISE INFO 'table_name - % , Schema_name - %',table_name,schema_name;
    counts := (SELECT count(*) FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = schema_name);
    RAISE INFO 'Tables in schema: %',counts;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Call:

```
CALL gp_information_schema_test('dev.abc');
```

Comment: hey @joe, isnt it the same thing that I wrote in the question ? But for some reason it is returning the correct result

Comment: In the above, if I add another WHERE filter then again it stops working and giving me the previous result (incorrect result) , kind of a cached result.
i.e the query - SELECT count(*) FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = schema_name and table_name like '%abc%' gives me the same result as it would have given me without --> table_name like '%abc%'